# Unhandled promise rejection: undefined is not an object (evaluating _expoLocation.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync)

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, expo

I'm trying to get the user location in React Native with Expo (Managed Workflow for Android) following the [official example](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/#usage) for `expo-location`. Here is my function:

```js
import Location from 'expo-location';

const handleLocationFinder = async () => {
  const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
  if (status !== 'granted') {
    console.log('Permission denied. Enter the location manually.');
    return;
  }
  const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
  console.log(location);
};
```

However, when I call this function, I get this warning:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoLocation.default.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync')]
```

**What I tried**:

- Reinstall the app in the emulator;
- Fresh emulator;
- My actual phone (Android 8.0);
- Add `"permissions": ["ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"]` to `app.json` (although expo seems to do this);
- `expo upgrade`;
- Pray.

**Platform info** (after `expo upgrade`):

- Android 11.0 (Pixel 4 emulated)
- `expo`: 41.0.1
- `react-native`: sdk-41.0.0
- `expo-location`: 12.0.4

Comment: I am getting the same error right now when I use the now deprecated requestPermissionsAsync(); instead It works, besides the warning...

Comment: @PhilCowan, I actually gave up of struggling with expo and ejected to a bare workflow. After that, using `react-native-permissions` worked well.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue and when i changed:

```
import Location from "expo-location";
```

To:

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";
```

Like what in the documentation, it worked for me.